# How to aggregate more than one column of many rows inside one in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

If my question is a bit obscure, here is what I mean, we can aggregate one column of multiple rows using `array_agg`, for instance I have this table

```
  foo  |  bar  |  baz
-------+-------+-------
   1   |  10   |  20
   1   |  12   |  23
   1   |  15   |  26
   1   |  16   |  21
```

If I invoke this query :

```
select
  foo,
  array_agg(bar) as bars
from table
group by (foo)
```

resulting in :

```
  foo  |  bars
-------+----------------
   1   |  {10,12,15,16}
```

What would be the query to have this table (using *bar,baz*) ?

```
  foo  |  barbazs  
-------+------------------------------------
   1   |  {{10,20},{12,23},{15,26},{16,21}}
```

I checked into [functions-aggregate (postgresql.org)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) but it doesn't seem to be any functions to have that effect or am I missing something ?

Comment: What happens with `array_agg(array[bar, baz])`?

Comment: @melpomene it happens that it works. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) has arrays as possible input values.

We just need a way to build an array from the two input colums `bar` and `baz`, which can be done using the [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT foo, array_agg(ARRAY[bar, baz]) as barbaz FROM table GROUP BY foo;
 foo |              barbaz               
-----+-----------------------------------
   1 | {{10,20},{12,23},{15,26},{16,21}}
```

**Note** : It also works with `DISTINCT` (`...array_agg(distinct array[bar,baz])...`)